# How to pass a string containing whitespace as parameter to where clause of a query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT `Sub_id`, `Sub_name`, `Course_id`, `Semester`, `Credits`, `Emp_id1`, `Emp_id2`, `Emp_id3`, `Study_hours` 
FROM `subject` 
WHERE `Sub_name` = 'Indian Economy-I'
```

[image: Data in the subject table]

I am stucked on this query as i am not getting the result.
I think is because of the whitespace in parameter.
I have also tried like but that too didn't work for me.

[image: Zero rows returned using like operator]

Comment: *I think is because of the whitespace in parameter.* Hardly. Check `HEX(subject.Sub_name)` and `HEX('Indian Economy-I')`, search for difference reason.

Comment: Nope it didn't work!

Comment: WHAT didn't work? Show both values.

Comment: Showing rows 0 -  0 (1 total, Query took 0.0029 seconds.)

SELECT Hex(Sub_name),Hex('Indian Economy-I') FROM `subject` WHERE Sub_id = 'SU008'



20496E6469616E2045636F6E6F6D792D49 || 496E6469616E2045636F6E6F6D792D49

Comment: And you do NOT see the space (hex code 20) at the beginning of a value in a table? use, for example, ```WHERE TRIM(`Sub_name`) = 'Indian Economy-I'```